# regex extract string between single quotes trim whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to extract a string between single quotes and trim any preceding or trailing whitespaces. I'm able to extract the string in between the single quotes using `(?<=')[^']+(?=')` however, it's the trim bit I am struggling with.

String: 
`message sent from '  joe bloggs     '`.

I'd like the result extracted by regex to be:
`joe bloggs`

Comment: It would be better if you tag the language you are using and share the code you have tried.

Comment: Please mention the language used.

Comment: Most regex solutions let you extract a sub-group. Which makes it easy here.. But this question without the precise technology used is useless.

Comment: Apologies, it's python. Here's an example of what I have so far https://regex101.com/r/vQqnaB/1

Comment: You should **[edit]** your own attempts into your question, along with sample inputs (preferable more than one), your current result, and why that's no good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe a simple regular expression like this should do the trick:

```
import re
s = "message sent from '  joe bloggs     '"
extracted_text = re.search('''(?<=')\s*[^']+?\s*(?=')''', s)
print extracted_text.group().strip() # output: 'joe bloggs'
```

Here is what this code does:

- `(?<=')` - positive look behind: makes sure that the text it is matching has a `'` in front of it.
- `\s*`- zero or more whitespaces.
- `[^']+?` - as many characters that aren't quotes.
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces, again.
- `(?=')` - Positive look ahead: makes sure that the text it's matching ends with a quote.
- Once it matches that, you get it by calling `match.group()`.
- Then you're left with the string `'  joe bloggs     '`. So you get rid of the whitespace by calling `str.strip()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, this has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it:

```
'\s*([^']+?)\s*'
```

- `'` match a quote
- `\s*` match optional spaces before to be ignored in the match
- `([^']+?)` capture your string
- `\s*` match optional spaces after to be ignored in the match
- `'` match a quote

You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/vQqnaB/2

```
import re
my_str = "message sent from '  joe bloggs     '"

content = re.search(r"'\s*([^']+?)\s*'", my_str).groups()[0]
print('%r' % content) # 'joe bloggs'
```

Comment: Your code captures the quotes, so you can't strip the whitespace.

Comment: The striped content will be in group 1

Comment: this only grabs the first occurrence of text between single quotes. `"message sent from 'joe' with email 'joe@example.com'"` won't capture `joe@example.com`

Answer (score -1):

If you indeed already get the text between single quotes, then the rest is as easy as

```
s = '  joe bloggs     '
result = s.strip()
```

Of course you could do it with regex, in which case I can recommend the excellent https://regex101.com/